# Increment Date by 35 Days and Store Results in Array

Tags: vb.net

Whilst I know 'how' to do this, in my head I'd like to be sure I'm making the best of the syntax to perform the task.
I am looking to take a date, and add increments of 35 days until it reaches a date in the future.
Is there a neater way to do this in VB.NET?

```
'\* define the end of the repeat period (where dteValuationDate is, say, 01/01/2016)...
dteReminderEndDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 15, dteValuationDate)
'\* define the start date for the loop (which is a specific date, say, 17/05/2016, and add 70 days to it)...
dteLoopStart = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 70, dteStartDate)          
intDateCount = 1            
While dteRollingDate < dteReminderEndDate
   '\* calculate the actual unadjusted rolling date...
   dteRollingDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (intDateCount * 35), dteLopStart)                
   _dteReminderDates(intDateCount) = dteRollingDate              
   intDateCount = intDateCount + 1                
   ReDim Preserve _dteReminderDates(intDateCount)
End While
```

So I only want to store the dates that fall before the end date, ie 01/01/2016+15 months. Whilst am comfortable that what I'm doing is basically 'correct', I'm keen to know if there are better (read neater) ways to do this?

Comment: Please stop using line-by-line commenting, let the code speak for itself

Answer (score 3):

I think this is actually you are looking for:

```
Dim startDate As Date = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2016")
Dim endDate As Date = Convert.ToDateTime("17/05/2016")
Dim PossibleDateList As List(Of Date) = New List(Of Date)
While startDate <= endDate
    PossibleDateList.Add(startDate)
    startDate = startDate.AddDays(35)
End While
```

Finally `PossibleDateList` will contains all required dates

Comment: Really neat approach, hadn't considered that. But I've just been asked to consider that the date array be two-dimensional, as I need to store the dates for several records (there are 35 records, but now three not the initial request of one, have the array of dates requirement, though this number may increase in the future). I think my original approach was designed to cater for this should it happen. So the array would be something like _dteReminderDates(a, intDateCount) = dteRollingDate